# MySQL get average of columns in different table according to datetime() and hour()

Tags: mysql, database

Here is the scenario

TABLE 1:

```
select buyprice,sellprice,datetime from zebpay order by id desc limit 10

# buyprice, sellprice, datetime
'1107705', '1057858', '2017-12-24 13:30:23'
'1105060', '1053927', '2017-12-24 13:25:23'
'1106381', '1056594', '2017-12-24 13:20:23'
'1115181', '1064998', '2017-12-24 13:15:22'
'1112749', '1062675', '2017-12-24 13:10:21'
'1111888', '1061853', '2017-12-24 13:05:21'
'1128365', '1080974', '2017-12-24 13:00:20'
'1127202', '1079859', '2017-12-24 12:55:20'
'1132226', '1084672', '2017-12-24 12:50:19'
'1132037', '1084492', '2017-12-24 12:45:19'
```

TABLE 2:

```
select buyprice,sellprice,datetime from coinsecure order by id desc limit 10

# buyprice, sellprice, datetime
'1045000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:32:44'
'1050000', '1045000', '2017-12-24 13:31:43'
'1050000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:30:41'
'1045000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:29:39'
'1048000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:28:37'
'1048000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:27:35'
'1048000', '1042000', '2017-12-24 13:26:33'
'1050000', '1048199', '2017-12-24 13:25:30'
'1050000', '1048199', '2017-12-24 13:24:29'
'1050000', '1048199', '2017-12-24 13:23:27'
```

I want to get the average of buy price and sell price by first adding table1 buyprice with table2 buy price then finding the average according to each minute of all datetime

for example,i should get a table something like this

```
# buyprice,sellprice,datetime
'1045000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:55:00'
'1050000', '1045000', '2017-12-24 13:50:00'
'1050000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:45:00'
'1045000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:40:00'
'1048000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:35:00'
'1048000', '1042100', '2017-12-24 13:30:00'
'1048000', '1042000', '2017-12-24 13:25:00'
'1050000', '1048199', '2017-12-24 13:20:00'
'1050000', '1048199', '2017-12-24 13:15:00'
'1050000', '1048199', '2017-12-24 13:10:00'
```

Here all the values between 2017-12-24 13:55:00 2017-12-24 13:50:00
is used to get average at 2017-12-24 13:55:00

it can be in interval of 5 minutes or 1 minute or one hour..the main point is to get as much as possible values for precise graph.

if a value in one table is not present for given time interval it can be taken zero

Comment: like getting output form this querry:SELECT ROUND(AVG(buyprice),2 ) as buyprice,ROUND(AVG(sellprice),2 ) as sellprice,datetime FROM zebpay group by date(datetime),hour(datetime) order by datetime desc

Comment: This is not a minimal question IMO.  Please show a small sample data set and explain exactly what the output should be and why.  `something like this` is not very helpful.